# how to create hdf5 file from numpy dataset files

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5

I have 1970 `.npy` files as features for MSVD dataset. I want to create one `.hdf5` file from these numpy files.

```
import os 
import numpy as np
import hdf5


TRAIN_FEATURE_DIR = "MSVD"   

for filename in os.listdir(TRAIN_FEATURE_DIR):
    f = np.load(os.path.join(TRAIN_FEATURE_DIR, filename))
...
```

Comment: Do you know how to `load` those `npy` files?  How to iterate over the directory?  How to create a HDF5 file with `h5py`?  And create `groups` and `datasets`?  There pieces are all there.

Comment: @hpaulj   I know to load and iterate files only, but I do not know how to create groups and datasets

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) how you have applied that knowledge to the current problem.

Comment: The `h5py` documentation is pretty good.  But experiment with simple cases first.

Comment: @J_H the question is updated

Comment: We have [a pickled object](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html), `f`. I have no idea what is in the loaded file, nor what attributes `f` has. You've not cited any h5py documentation, and have not shown any attempts to create an `.hdf5` file. I don't know what result you were hoping your question would elicit. Be specific, help us to help you.

Comment: @J_H , f shape is (299x299x3). I want to grope these numpy files to HDF5 file, where the keys represent the names of numpy files and the values represent the corresponding contents (numpy files) of these keys

Comment: What part of the tutorial / documentation was unclear? I see no code attempting to save `f`, and I see no cited URLs.

Comment: @J_H , I read this documentation: (https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html). But there is no code nor case similar my issue

Comment: I am not yet understanding your use case. Apparently some code is going to read an .hdf but I haven't seen that, and apparently you have no other instances of manipulating .hdf files in your codebase? Hmmm. Maybe you'd prefer to use a different format. Tell you what! Why don't you create a DataFrame from that array, and then use .to_hdf() when creating a new file? Show us that, and we can go from there. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html We want to round-trip data back and forth between memory and .hdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dataset from an array is easy. Example below loops over all `.npy` files in a folder and creates 1 dataset for each array. (FYI, I prefer `glob.iglob()` to get the filenames using a wildcard.) Dataset name is the same as the filename.

```
import glob 
import numpy as np
import h5py

with h5py.File('SO_74788877.h5','w') as h5f:
    for filename in glob.iglob('*.npy'):
        arr = np.load(filename)
        h5f.create_dataset(filename,data=arr)
```

This code shows how to access the dataset names and values from the H5 file created above. (`dataset` is a dataset object which behaves like a numpy array in many instances):

```
with h5py.File('SO_74788877.h5','r') as h5f:
    for name, dataset in h5f.items():
        print(name, dataset.shape, dataset.dtype)
```